# quickfix window in vertical split with maximum height

Tags: vim, pep8, python-mode

I have recently started using vim plugins and was trying to setup python-mode with pep8. I wanted to see split the window vertically. I was able to achieve it using autocmd commad as :

```
:autocmd FileType qf wincmd L
```

But now height of file window and quickfix window reduces to 10. Is there a way to change this to max possible height ?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to adjust the height of pymode quickfix window, following [documentation](https://github.com/klen/python-mode/blob/develop/doc/pymode.txt) you can try to change these settings in your `.vimrc`

```
let g:pymode_quickfix_minheight = 3
let g:pymode_quickfix_maxheight = 6
```

If you need just to open a quickfix window vertically, you can do so by using [`:vert`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3Avert) command

```
:vert copen
```

Comment: is it possible to adjust the variable based on window size ? I want it to be always equal to the size of the window.  also could you please point me how to navigate from 1 error to another ?

Comment: About pointing to navigate - read documentation, as mentioned romainl, and use Google.

Comment: This function `pymode#quickfix_open(onlyRecognized, maxHeight, minHeight, jumpError)` in `python-mode/autoload/pymode.vim` seems to be probably responsible for size adjustment of the quickfix. You can change it, or you can ask for this feature at [issue tracker](https://github.com/klen/python-mode/issues).